# Wallpaper app using Fragment want to save scroll position of recyclerview (firebase)

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

This code belongs to Fragment wallpaper, over here it doent save its position. if i scroll down and click on that wallpaper it opens and then when i go back recycler view will go to top position

```
public class wallpaper extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recview;
    myadapter adapter;
    View view;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallpaper, container, false);

        recview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recview);

        //3 for a 5 when the user rotates the phone
        if (getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            recview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        } else {
            recview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
        }
        //Calling source and layout from Model.class
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Wallpapers"), model.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new myadapter(options);

        recview.setAdapter(adapter);


        FloatingActionButton fabwallbtn = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabwallpaperbutton);
        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Drawer_Layout);
        fabwallbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Recyclerview doesnt save its position.

Comment: You should save a scroll position. See more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587745/how-to-save-and-restore-scrolling-position-of-the-recyclerview-in-a-fragment-whe

Comment: Did Alexander's recommendation help?

Comment: can we connect on teams @AlexMamo Please